# Need to tap twice on touchscreen to click button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that at one point brings up another window where the user can enter text in a field that is selected on open then click OK to save the text. This is working correctly on my desktop using a mouse, but when I run the application on a tablet (Surface Pro) the OK button needs to be tapped twice to save the text. The first tap highlights the button, then the second tap clicks it. Is there any way to allow the user to click the button with just one tap on the screen?

This only happens when the application switches to the new window. The main window only requires one tap to click buttons (Though I have noticed that they require two when switching back to the main window). It seems like this issue has to do with focus or something because if I tap somewhere on the new window before clicking OK, I can tap OK once and it will trigger the click event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16413882/345659

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this in your code:

```
textBox1.Focus();
```

The other place to consider is the Tab order of the items on the form. Once the focus leaves the textbox, it moves to the next highest tab order object. It should be the OK button.

You can adjust the Tab order by looking at the properties of the objects on the form.

Comment: I already have textBox.Focus() and that works in that when the window pops up, the text box is selected and you can type to add text to it without clicking anything, but it still requires two taps to click OK. I will look into the tab order to see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in WPF combined with a touch display.

Because the textbox is focused, and you press the button, the textbox gets unfocused and the button gets focus. When the button has focus, you just have to press it in order to save your text.

There really isn't a thing you can do about it, since the touchscreen focuses first on the button before you can fire the event (I think it probaly is a kind of a safety feature).

Comment: This is what I feared. This is pretty disappointing, it makes my application much less user friendly if they always have to tap OK twice in order to click it. Oh well

Comment: @JacobCM Well there is a workaround, but i don't know if it will fit your application. There is a way for touchscreens to adjust the driver so a single tap becomes a double tap (I read about this while looking for an answer for you). I have no idea how to achieve this, or that it would even make sense to implement it

Comment: I never thought of that, that is an interesting solution. I'm not sure if this will work with my application but I will look into that thanks